# Como Colocar Dois join em um só

Tags: cakephp

```
$this->loadModel('Funcionario');
$id_Defensor = $this->Funcionario->find('list', array(
        'fields' => ['Funcionario.id'],
        'conditions' => array('EspecializadasFuncionario.especializada_id' => $idAgendamentos),
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'especializadas_funcionarios', 
                'alias' => 'EspecializadasFuncionario', 
                'type' => 'INNER', 
                'conditions' => array('EspecializadasFuncionario.funcionario_id = Funcionario.id'),
    )
)
));
debug($id_Defensor);

$this->loadModel('Funcionario');
$nome_func = $this->Funcionario->find('list', array(
        'fields' => ['Pessoa.id', 'Pessoa.nome'],
        'conditions' => array('Funcionario.id' => $funcionario_id),
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'pessoas', 
                'alias' => 'Pessoa', 
                'type' => 'INNER', 
                'conditions' => array('Pessoa.id = Funcionario.pessoa_id'),
    )
)
));
debug($nome_func);
```

Nesse caso eu quero retornar o id do funcionario e o nome da pessoa na mesma consulta.

Comment: Você pode fazer um alias para o campo, seque o exemplo.
[CakePhp Virtual Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries)

Comment: Você está fazendo uma consulta para retornar valores para uma listagem de select na view?